# Is it possible to play a specific section repeatedly using youtube javascript api?

Tags: javascript, youtube, youtube-javascript-api

```
https://www.youtube.com/embed/kWoxV4HLgKg?playlist=kWoxV4HLgKg&autoplay=1&rel=0&start=8&end=10&loop=2%22%20frameborder=%220%22
```

The above URL will return to 1 second after playing from 8 seconds to 10 seconds.
Is it possible to replay from 8 seconds even after playback is completed in 10 seconds?

javascript code I made is as follows.

http://jsfiddle.net/negabaro/8k9zgr2L/

Thank you for reading my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This](https://jsfiddle.net/xzdhmejg/) fiddle looks like it has what you are looking for. It uses 2 approaches, and compares performance of them both. I believe `player2` is what you will want to look at to achieve what you are looking for.

Comment: Nice. Where did you find `.seekTo`, because I did not see it in the docs?

Comment: I didn't actually write this fiddle, just found on google :) But here is the link https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#seekTo